# WPF contents overlaps Window border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Update**

I've confirmed that this only seems to happen on a particular PC. I think it's somehow related to my hardware setup:

- A laptop which only has video out via USB-C
- A third party USB-C to HDMI adapter
- Unbranded HDMI cable
- An Ultrawide monitor, which I think might be pushing the limits of HDMI and/or the adapter I'm using

When I recently bought the adapter, I found something a little "off" with the video quality, as if it's scaling pixels despite Windows saying it's native resolution.

I've read a lot about USB-C video being a little unreliable. I wonder whether Windows or the Laptop might get confused about the resolution when waking up from sleep. This might conflict with the WPF display units.

---

**Original Question**

I must be missing something obvious, but how do I build a simple WPF window which actually fits within the Window Frame?

The problem:

[image]

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015, although the same thing happens with Kaxaml. This XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Results in the content, in this case a Grid, overhanging the window by a pixel or two:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How you managed to do this remains a mystery. I just can't reproduce this...

But I do have something you can try.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ClipToBounds="True">
    <Grid> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Edit

Actually I suddenly realized this only stops the extra pixels from visually appearing. This means that the Grid is still bigger than it should, and if there are contents that are rendered there, they are going to be clipped away. But if there are nothing rendered, this should at least make this window looks normal.

Anyway, this happening could be related to some weird windows theme that you applied or something? Some themes that made the window rendered smaller than what it should or something?

Comment: This is a fresh Dell PC, with no custom theme that I know of. ClipToBound doesn't seem to be valid on the Window, but is ok on the Grid. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @Matt It happens to new projects that you create? Or is this some old project that you ported to this new PC?

Comment: It happens to all new and old projects I've tried on this PC. I just tried another PC, which theoretically has the same OS version, and it doesn't happen. So it looks like something weird on this one. I wonder if Dell included something in their "plain" Windows install.

Comment: @Matt Try building it on this new PC, then bring the executable to another PC, see if it happens. If it happens, it has nothing to do with your code/VS etc - it's purely your PC.

Comment: It's fixed, for now, and I think it's somehow related to video connections. I'll do some troubleshooting and try to reproduce...

Comment: InvalidOperationException: ClipToBounds is not valid for Window.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. However it only appears on the screen(s) attached to the laptop dock, not on the laptop screen.

Comment: @Anders then the best guess i can give is that the screens do not have the same scaling set, or simply different dpi.